# failure of resumable php-upload to google drive

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I'm trying resumable upload of my file (105mb) to google drive by this php-script:

```
$client->setDefer(true);
$chunkSize = 1024 * 1024 * 10;
$request = $service->files->create(
    $fileMetadata,
    [
        "mimeType" => $mimeType,
        "uploadType" => "resumable",
        'fields' => 'id'
    ]
);
$media = new Google_Http_MediaFileUpload($client, $request, $mimeType, null, true, $chunkSize);
$media->setFileSize(filesize($path));
$media->setChunkSize($chunkSize);

$status = false;
$handle = fopen($path, "rb");
$k = 1;
while (!$status && !feof($handle)) {
    $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSize);
    echo $k . '<br>';
    try {
        $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'error - ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
    $k++;
}
$result = false;
if ($status != false) {
    $result = $status;
}
fclose($handle);
$client->setDefer(false);
```

Code in the while construction executes 10 times and finally on 11 got the error:

> [Google_Service_Exception]
>   Invalid request.  There were 394240 byte(s) (or more) in the request
>   body.  There should have been 372414 byte(s) (starting at offset
>   78643200 and ending at offset 79015613) according to the Content-Range
>   header. (400)

What am i doing wrong? I've tried to increase chunk size to 100 mb, code is executes without errors, but variable $result is empty and file didn't upload.
Simple upload without chunks works, but i need to upload big files.

Comment: Are you using the [Google php client library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client)? I noticed that they have encountered the same issue but I think this was resolved using the updated version of the library.

Comment: Yes, i installed this library by composer:
"google/apiclient": "^2"
it's last version as i know